# Setting individual instances of a class to input from class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am working on a terminal based game of sorts, and I want players to have a more personal experience by allowing them to choose their character's names. I learned that I can use a class method to define input on all attributes of the object; however, if I want to only do it for one how would I do so? What I have for the objects and instances is:

```
import random as rand
class Character:
    def __init__(self, characterType, name, damage, health, points):
        self.characterType = characterType
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.health = health
        self.points = points
    @classmethod
    def get_name(cls):
        return cls(
            self.characterType,
            input("Enter your {self.characterType}'s name. ".format, self.characterType),
            self.damage,
            self.health,
            self.points,
        )
```

Comment: You have tagged this with `python-3.x` but you are using `raw_input`. Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: The concept here is flawed.  When you're running a class method, there is no "self".  All you have is the class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be a part of the class.  Let the class handle the behavior, let the caller decide the policy and the I/O.  So:

```
import random as rand
class Character:
    def __init__(self, characterType, name, damage, health, points):
        self.characterType = characterType
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.health = health
        self.points = points

name = input(f"Enter your {characterType}'s name:")
newchar = Character( characterType, name, damage, health, points )
```

Comment: I first had this solution; however, when I create more than one object, I'd have to create another name variable

Comment: Well, you will certainly ask each new user for their name.  The "name" variable doesn't mean anything; the string is stored in the object.